# Function in same Session w/diff params become increasingly slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, function, session

Issue:

PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

Client is Data Grip and same behavior from my report server which uses the driver that comes with Jaspersoft

I am running the same function for reporting with different parameters multiple times under the same session. Also does the same thing using the same parameters.

These are being one run one after the other and not at the same time.

The result only has a few rows but does read from quite a few tables, no writes.

It is just table joins and selects no inputs or updates to the tables themselves (would like to be able to post query but can't for security reasons).

After I run the function a few times it starts to slow down and gets to an unacceptable level. For example one of the functions goes from 1 second to over 90+ seconds (that is where I stopped testing).

Troubleshooting:

I have gone to the server and terminated the session and after that it starts to run normally for a few runs.

The standard report does use a temp table but I have removed that for testing.
I have run the following after it starts having the issue to try and fix the issue.

VACUUM all touched tables; -- I know this should not be required as there are no major changes to these tables but was trying pretty much anything.
Language plpgsql.

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION DEFAULT;
RESET ALL;
DEALLOCATE ALL;
CLOSE ALL;
UNLISTEN *;
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock_all();
DISCARD PLANS;
DISCARD SEQUENCES;
DISCARD TEMP;
```

There does not seem to be a good way to terminate idle connections without a separate application or script run through a job.

Comment: Postgres version? What is the function code?

Comment: This is not a general feature of function use.  It must have something to do with the contents of your function (or perhaps your client), it is unlikely we can debug it without seeing it.  What if you call with the same parameters each time?  Which pl language are you using?  What client are you using?  Where are your transaction boundaries?

Comment: Version is 11 (sorry thought I put that).
It is just table joins and selects no inputs or updates to the tables themselves (would like to be able to post query but can't for security reasons).
I have tried with the same parameters and after a few runs it does the exact same thing.
Client is Data Grip and same behavior from my report server which uses the driver that comes with Jaspersoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a known issue but seldom talked about issue with parameters in Execution Plans where starting with the 6th run in the same session it will take a lot longer to run.  The solution is to just set the execution plan to force_custom_plan and it works fine or did in my case.

ALTER FUNCTION xy SET plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan;